# HTML5 to Native applications security concerns

Tags: html, security, mobile, native

Would you choose to build an application using HTML5 but when security is a priority to your client?

Let's say creating HTML5 mobile application for a bank where the data are really sensitive, what would be the technology you would use, native or HTML5?

Any good tutorial on the internet to a subject like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Security from what kind of attack?

Comment: In general, sniffing the network, malwares looking for other applications activities, browsers addons sniffing your website, since this will be for all devices and desktops if you need to achieve cross platform. Then you should look for the supporting security standards, like certificates or protected username password credentials, using https I guess to trasport! How to prove if this is a technology that you can trust and move forward implement sensitive applications to benefit from 1 language to rule them all.

Answer (score 1):

Security on the client side isn't really your problem.  You need to be worried about security on the *server* side.  You have to assume that no matter what kind of code you put into your client, someone will hack it/reverse engineer it.  Since you don't have control over the client, you must focus your efforts on the server.  Since it is your server's API that must be secured, the client platform doesn't really matter too much, provided you use HTTPS so as to encrypt/protect the information in transit and you don't leak sensitive server side info to the client.

Building a secure web app is a big job, much bigger than can be answered on SO.  I highly recommend getting and reading copy of [The Web Application Hacker's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118026470) (which I've read and enjoyed), or the newer book that looks promising, [Web Application Defender's Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118362187).

Comment: Great one, thank you, I think it was what I needed so far. Will mark this as answer in couple of day if no one has something to add. Thank you for your time.